# JAVA + HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate

Comecei a utilizar o hibernate e sou bem leigo no assunto, o que quero realmente saber é: Quando mapeamos uma classe para o hibernate criar automaticamente a tabela no banco de dados, é possível controlar o que será executado no banco?

Por exemplo: Se eu alterar o nome de um atributo ou adicionar algum atributo na minha classe, consigo desabilitar a função de alterar o banco automaticamente?
Como posso ter este tipo de controle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir algumas restrições por meio das anotações do *framework*, uma delas é a anotação `@Transient` que permite ignorar o mapeamento do campo na tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente aconselho você a dar uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/5165064) que fala sobre as estratégias de execução de comandos DDL utilizando hibernate.

Se você quer simplesmente alterar o atributo em java e não quer que essa alteração mude o nome da coluna no banco, você precisa anotar seu atributo com a annotation [@Column](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)

```java
@Column(name = "TBG_MINHA_COLUNA")
private String myColumn;
```

Já para inibir o mapeamento automático do atributo pelo hibernate, você deve anotar ele com [@Transient](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) que especifica que o atributo não será persistido.